# Export comments only from Okular Pdf-reader (tangling)

Tags: pdf, okular

I use Okular annotations for my Pdfs and use the highlighting and underline-features quite frequently.

From some documents it would be nice to **export all the passages, that have been highlighted to a (preferably) plain text document**, so I can work with these notes, without having to handcopy them again for a second time.

I tried to access the .okular document archive / xml-data, but I couldn't reach the important data.